# How to fix typescript error 'name' does not exist in type 'ByRoleOptions' when querying by accessible name using getByRole in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a component that renders a list of filters as removable chips which I am trying to test using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro). I am trying to do query by accessible name as explained [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole) using `getByRole`.

**component**:

```
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import React from 'react';
import './FilterChips.less';
import { Filters } from './types';

export type FilterChipsProps = {
    filters: Filters,
};

export const FilterChips = (props: FilterChipsProps) => {

    const { filters } = props;

    const people = filters.people
                        ? filters.people.map((person: any) => (
                            <Chip
                                icon={<PersonIcon />}
                                label={`${person.Name} (${person.Id})`}
                                key={person.Id}
                                className='chips'
                                role='filter-chip'
                            />
                        ))
                        : [];

    return people.length > 0
                ? (
                    <div className='filters'>
                        <span>Filters:   </span>
                        {people}
                    </div>
                )
                :
                null;
};
```

**Test**:

```
test('that filters are rendered properly', async () => {
    const filters = {
        people: [
            { Id: '1', Name: 'Hermione Granger' },
            { Id: '2', Name: 'Albus Dumbledore' },
        ],
    };
    const props = { filters };
    const { getByRole } = render(<FilterChips {...props} />);
    const PersonFilter = getByRole('filter-chip', { name: `${filters.people[0].Name} (${filters.people[0].Id})` });
    expect(PersonFilter).toBeDefined();
});
```

But I am getting a typescript error:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ByRoleOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'ByRoleOptions'
```

How do I fix this?

I tried a couple of things to fix this. I imported `getByRole` directly from `@testing-library/dom` and deconstructed `container` from rendered component

`const { container } = render(<FilterChips {...props} />);`

and then tried to do query by accessible name as following

```
const PersonFilter = getByRole(container, 'filter-chip', { name: '${filters.people[0].Name} (${filters.people[0].Id})' });
```

But this is also throwing the same error. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Opened an issue here: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/636

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore ts preceding the problematic line with:

```
//@ts-ignore
const PersonFilter = getByRole('filter-chip', { name: `${filters.people[0].Name} (${filters.people[0].Id})` });
```

This will ignore all typescript alerts and treat that next line as if it were plain javascript

Answer (score -1):

following this example in the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole) (scroll to the end of the section linked and click on the 'React' tab):

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

const { getByRole } = render(<MyComponent />)
const dialogContainer = getByRole('dialog')
```

your code should be:

```
const { getByRole } = render(<FilterChips {...props} />);
const PersonFilter = getByRole(`${filters.people[0].Name} (${filters.people[0].Id})`);
```

Comment: You can either manually pass in the container like OP did, get it from the  object returned from render(), or use it from screen. https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#level